# Контэйнер не растягиваются на всю ширину дочерних компонентов

Tags: html, css

Есть контейнер, div. 
Его стили:

```css
    position: fixed !important;
    top: auto !important;
    bottom: 10px !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    right: auto !important;
    display: flex !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translate(0px, 0px) !important;
    z-index: 2147483647 !important;
    background-color: #f47821 !important;
    border-radius: 23px !important;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) !important;
    height: 45px !important;
    padding: 0 5px !important;
    flex-direction: row !important;
```

И внутри пять одинаковых чайл компонентов за исключением того, что у первого компонента помимо иконки есть текст. Их стили:

```css
    display: flex !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    flex: 0 0 auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    flex-direction: row!important;
    align-items: stretch!important;
    justify-content: stretch!important;
```

Почему последний чайлд скрывается ? Если нужны доп сведения - скажите.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выложите фрагменты HTML и CSS кода на CodePen, чтобы на Вашем примере поискать и показать решение проблемы

Comment: для чего столько плохого тона (important) ?

Comment: @MaximLensky скорее всего стилизует сторонний виджет на сайте

Comment: @Vearo наверно всё равно столько "матерится" не надо

Comment: @MaximLensky я и не спорю))